# Will Googlebot automatically attempt to index sitemap.xml?

Tags: seo, sitemap, googlebot

Will Googlebot automatically attempt to index sitemap.xml if my sitemap.xml file wasn't submitted to Google? For example, will Googlebot attempt to index http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml if by chance the file is there?

Google's resource say to submit, but what Googlebot does is a separate question.
http://support.google.com/sites/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=100283

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitemap file can have any name and path. So, I don't think that google will look for it, if it is not explicitly specified in robots.txt.

```
User-agent: *
Sitemap: sitemap.xml
```

Comment: In robot.txt we could also assign it as a [Sitemap index file](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index) in case we want to use multiple sitemap files.